# Se mueve de lugar el parámetro al pasarlo mvc y javascript

Tags: javascript, mvc, entity-framework-6

hola tengo el siguiente problema.

en un controlador paso 3 parametros con get.

```
public async Task<FileStreamResult> ExportPdf(string g, string t, string c)
{ ... }
```

con esta ruta :

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "ExportPDF", 
                 url: "ExportPDF/{g}/{t}/{c}", 
            defaults: new { 
                controller = "calificaciones", 
                    action = "ExportPDF", 
                         g = "", 
                         t = "", 
                         c = ""});
```

Y armo la URL con el siguiente código Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ObtenerValor() {
        var url = "@Url.Action("ExportPdf", "calificaciones",new { g = "param-g", t = "param-t", c = "param-c" } )";
        url = url.replace("param-g", document.getElementById("gente").value);
        url = url.replace("param-t", document.getElementById("tarea").value);
        url = url.replace("param-c", document.getElementById("calif").value);

        window.open(url, '_blank');
        document.getElementById("gente").value = "";
        document.getElementById("tarea").value = "";
        document.getElementById("calif").value = "";
    };
```

El problema surge cuando `gente` y `calif` están vacíos, pero en `tarea` no.

El controlador me recibe el contenido de la URL en el primer parámetro, el cual corresponde a gente.

¿Cómo podría solucionar esto?

Comment: No conozco el framework, pero si lo que necesitas es si o si un valor podrias probar url = url.replace("param-g", (document.getElementById("gente").value || '0' ));

Comment: @GerardoRosciano gracias ya lo solucione

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es cómo estás montando las rutas.

La ruta genera urls del tipo:

http:///ExportPDF/{valor-g}/{valor-t}/{valor-c}

Si por ejemplo (como en el caso que comentas) valor-g y valor-t son vacíos la url que se va a generar es http://{miservidor}/ExportPDF///{valor-c}
Lo cual en la mayoría de los servidores web se va a interpretar como equivalente a http://{miservidor}/ExportPDF/{valor-c}
Así que el controlador interpreta que el valor recibido corresponde al primer parámetro, en este caso "g".

Las opciones que se me ocurren pasan por:

- Cambiar la forma de generar las rutas para que valores vacíos no causen este problema
- Reemplazar los valores vacíos por algún tipo de cadena que represente un valor no válido para evitar errores. Por ejemplo si utilizas como cadena para valores vacíos "empty". En javascript deberías utilizar esta cadena en caso de que el input se encuentre vacío. La url generada sería http://{miservidor}/ExportPDF/empty/empty/{valor-c}.
  En este caso en el controlador tendrías que reemplazar los valores "empty" por cadenas vacías antes de tratarlos.